# Return date as ddmmyyyy in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, date-formatting

I need the date as `ddmmyyyy` without any spacers.

How can I do this?

I can get `yyyymmdd` using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, [MyDateTime], 112)`

But I need the reverse of this.

SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`CONVERT` style 103 is dd/mm/yyyy. Then use the `REPLACE` function to eliminate the slashes.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), [MyDateTime], 103), '/', '')
```

Comment: This is ok but you need a string origin date with slashes, otherwise a ddmmyyyy need to add the separators.

Answer (score 21):

Just for the record, since SQL 2012 you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), as simple as:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddMMyyyy')
```

(op question is specific about SQL 2008)

Comment: Works on SQL azure also. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what took them so long... Best guess: SQL syntax s!%"$ so hard they were unable to implement it sooner.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), THEDATE, 103), '/', '') AS [DDMMYYYY]
```

As seen here: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I've been doing it like this for years;

```
print convert(char,getdate(),103)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it without replacing the slashes

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)
```

This would return: "YYYYMMDD"

Comment: The OP specifically says that is not what he wants

Comment: This is not pertinent with the question, the need is a "ddmmyyyy" format

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(convert(VARCHAR,getdate(),103),'/','')

select right(convert(VARCHAR,getdate(),112),2) + 
       substring(convert(VARCHAR,getdate(),112),5,2) + 
       left(convert(VARCHAR,getdate(),112),4)
```

Comment: You should format your answer so the "code" appears as such. In the text editor for answers there's button that looks like {}. Select text and then push that button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF('01012020', 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-'), 103);
```

It works with SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query to format datetime in sql server

```
FORMAT (frr.valid_from , 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```