# Convert SQL Server 2008 R2 Datetime to Varchar in ddmmyyyyhhmm format

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking to convert a Datetime to Varchar(12) in ddmmyyyyhhmm format.

I can get ddmmyyyy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770542/return-date-as-ddmmyyyy-in-sql-server). But is there an easy way to get the entire string using a single conversion code (like 103 or 133) or should I get date and time separately then merge it.

Thanks

Update : Found the answer with some help from scott.

```
Replace(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),'/','') + Replace(CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108),':','')
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I started my research few hours back with the link you posted and also tried [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql). But I couldn't find a direct conversion codel like 103 or 113.

Comment: Umm, what about 131? All you need to do is strip out the `/`, `:`, and space (and truncate off the milliseconds).

Comment: It's Hijri calendar system. Getdate() gives me year-1434.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain . Thanks for your help. I managed to get the result with two convert and replace statments. `code`  SELECT Replace(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),'/','') + Replace(CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108),':','')

Comment: If you solved your own problem, you should either delete this question or post your own answer and mark it accepted in two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),'/','') + Replace(CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108),':','')
```